# Displays all dates in the current month

Tags: php, json

I have the data I want to display the date and by the month.

How to display the date in the month to the current month, in php by displaying on *json*?

Example:

```
Feb = (1=1),(2=1),(3=3),(4=2),(5=1),(6=3)....28

etc...
```

My date:

```
  |      date  |     IP       
===============================
  | 2015-02-01 | 10.88.25.139 |
  | 2015-02-02 | 10.88.25.138 |
  | 2015-02-03 | 10.88.25.130 |
  | 2015-02-03 | 10.88.25.131 |
  | 2015-02-03 | 10.88.25.132 |
  | 2015-02-04 | 10.88.25.139 |
  | 2015-02-04 | 10.88.25.138 |
  | 2015-02-05 | 10.88.25.131 |
  | 2015-02-06 | 10.88.25.131 |
  | 2015-02-06 | 10.88.25.131 |
  | 2015-02-06 | 10.88.25.131 |
```

Comment: So what type of json format you need exactly? can you share a sample?

Comment: yes I would expect from php encoded json, from the first day of how many ip. example date 1 = have 2 ip

Comment: It means JSON data would be like {"2015-02-01":"2", "2015-02-02":"1"}. correct?

Comment: it's true , yes, like the example

Comment: from where these records come?

Comment: @Rushil Panchigar, from current month

Comment: no i means to these records  | 2015-02-01 | 10.88.25.139 | [date and time] is that comes from db then you should use count sql function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346395/php-array-containing-all-dates-of-the-current-month have a look here it displays days in month adjust as per your need

Comment: thanks @smarttechy.. it solved thank you for the information you provide

Comment: @irwandwiyanto I'm posting it as answer then ..mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer `http://stackoverflow.com/a/13346468/6390490`

You can use the solution

```
// for each day in the month
for($i = 1; $i <=  date('t'); $i++)
{
   // add the date to the dates array
   $dates[] = date('Y') . "-" . date('m') . "-" . str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

// show the dates array
var_dump($dates);
```

It consists of simple date function of php